# What is the best way to create a subsite where newly hired employees can fill out forms on the site?

Tags: 2013, intranet

I am creating a subsite on my company's sharepoint server and wish to have all relevant forms available to be filled out on the site itself without the user needing to have certain software (i.e infopath).  How can I go about doing this?

Thank you,
Austin

Answer (score 1):

If you have SharePoint enterprise edition, you can publish InfoPath forms to SharePoint which do not require the user to have InfoPath installed.

Without this, you can create SharePoint lists that contain all of the fields. It won't be nearly as pretty unless you can modify the code though.

Alternatively you could look at Word or PDF based forms, but those would obviously require a minimum level of desktop software.

Answer (score 1):

You can create lists with relevant columns, like for example

```
Employee Name - Single Line of text
Employee Designation - single line of text
Employee Id - Number (Unique and Required)
```

You can create different lists like this and can use the "NewItem.aspx" page related to them as your forms. To make those forms more visually appealing you need to change their xslt in sharepoint designer.